# How do I return the first 3 or the last 2 documents of the mongodb collection in one query?

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection `users` with 20 documents in it and i want to return the first 3 or the last 2 documents of it by creating ONLY one query for it.

Comment: ok but based on what creteria? you know which which one of those before sending the query? or this will be decided while the query is running? give some sample data if you can and the expected output, `$limit` stage needs a number not a mongo-expression, also `$sort` needs a field not a mongo-expression,  but maybe there is solution for your case

Comment: @Takis_ that's the problem there's no criteria and in this task supposedly doesn't matter what data is inside, so that's why i can't use any fields from it

Comment: what do you mean there is no creteria? its just random? making dynamic queries can be done in the application(if we know the query before send it), or on server, maybe your case can be done on application before sending the query

Comment: @Takis_ how come?